# $nse$ for which simple group was determined?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\omega(G)$ be the set of element orders of $G$. Let $k\in\omega(G)$ and $m_k$ be the number of elements of order $k$ in $G$. Set $nse(G):= \{m_k : k \in\omega(G)\}$. Whould you please let me know the set of $nse$ for which simple group was determined? And also was the $nse(PSL(n,q))$ determined?

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret "was determined". It is unlikely that ${\rm nse}({\rm PSL}(2,100003))$ has been determined, but it would be very easy to do so. But just to find all the element orders of ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$, you would need to be able to factorize $q^n-1$, which is a difficult problem. I think Dietrich Burde in his answer is addressing a different problem about whether the isomorphism type of a simple group is determined by ${\rm nse}(G)$.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but still the literature on this different problem also gives several cases where $nse(G)$ has been "determined", and the numbers are listed. This was my interpretation of "was determined". Most likely of course one can compute each of these cases in a milisecond.

Comment: Perhaps that was a slight exaggeration. It took about 80 milliseconds to do the computation for $M_{24}$!

Answer (score 4):

I found explicit results for $nse(G)$ for many finite simple groups $G$. Indeed, there is a large literature on the characterisation of finite simple groups $G$ by their order $\mid G\mid$ and the set $nse(G)$. The conjecture is that every finite simple group is characterised by $\mid G\mid$ and $nse(G)$. This has been achieved for several cases, but is still open in general. Several groups $PSL(n,q)$ and alternating groups have been treated, and all sporadic groups (see [here](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498812501587)).

One reference (as an example) lists the sets $nse(G)$ for Mathieu groups, see [here](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/139992/ArchMathRetro_046-2010-1_2.pdf). The sets $nse(M_{11}),\ldots , nse(M_{24})$ are given by
$$
nse(M_{11} ) = \{1, 165, 440, 990, 1584, 1320, 1980, 1440\},
$$

$$
nse(M_{12} ) = \{1, 891, 4400, 5940, 9504, 23760, 9504, 17280\}, 
$$

$$
etc. 
$$

Comment: But computing this information for the Mathieu groups can be done in milliseconds, so I am not sure if it is relevant to look for references.

Comment: The reference is indeed not relevant for the numbers. I just wanted to give an example here (for those not computing this in a milisecond). The reference is nevertheless useful for this topic, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention and your answer. In all your example order of group is a definite number. For example $nse(PSL(2,p))=\{1,p^2-1,p(p-1)/2\phi(d),p(p-1)/2\phi(s)\}$, where $\phi$ is Euler function and $d\mid (q+1)/2$ and $s\mid(q-1)/2$. What I want to know is this if there is determine $nse$ of some simple group for instance $PSL(n,p)$, where $n\neq2$?

Comment: Yes, for several cases, e.g., for $PSL(3,4)$ see [here](http://www.scienceasia.org/2013.39.n4/scias39_436.pdf). We have $nse(PSL(3,4)) = \{1, 315, 2240, 3780, 5760,
8064\}$. For $PSL(3,7)$ see [here](http://journals.ku.edu.kw/kjs/index.php/KJS/article/view/391), etc. The question is, what do you want with it, see Derek's comments.

Comment: @Anna For future reference, when asking a question, you should try to provide more context. In this case, it would have been helpful to state the result that you already know for ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$, because it makes it easier for people to understand what you are asking, and to help you.